# Download zip file from s3 using s3cmd issue

Tags: bash, ubuntu, amazon-s3, file-permissions

I have two issues I need help with on bash, linux and s3cmd.

First, I'm running into linux permission issue. I am trying to download zip files from a s3 bucket using `s3cmd` with following command in a bash `script.sh`:

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd get s3://<bucketname>/<folder>/zipfilename.tar.gz
```

I am seeing following error: `permission denied`.

If I try to run this command manually from command line on a linux machine, it works and downloads the file:

```
sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd get s3://<bucketname>/<folder>/zipfilename.tar.gz
```

I really don't want to use sudo in front of the command in the script. How do I get this command to work? Do I need to give `chown` permission to the `script.sh` which is actually sitting in a path i.e `/foldername/script.sh` or how do I get this get command to work?

Two: Once I get this command to work, How do I get it to download from s3 to the linux home dir: `~/` ? Do I have to specifically issue a command in the bash script: `cd ~/` before the above download command?

I really appreciate any help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, determine what's failing and the reason, otherwise you won't find the answer.

You can specify the destination in order to avoid permission problems when the script is invoked using a directory that's not writeable by that process

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd get s3:////zipfilename.tar.gz /path/to/writeable/destination/zipfilename.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all ask 1 question at a time.

For the first one you can simply change the permission with `chown` like :

```
chown “usertorunscript” filename
```

For the second :
If it is users home directory you can just specify it with

```
~user
```

as you said but I think writing the whole directory is safer so it will work for more users (if you need to)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I changed owner to ubuntu and following command works: /usr/bin/s3cmd get s3://zipfilename.tar.gz ~ubuntu